# On Change not working for second time

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm Calling onchange function from HTML. It works as expected for the first time. But Second time, its not. Not even the debugger is getting hitted in the function.

HTML

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Attachment.AttachmentFile, new { type = "file", onchange = "GetAttachmentFileName()", style = "display:none" })
```

JavaScript

```
function GetAttachmentFileName() {
      $("#Filesize").hide();
        if ($("#Attachment_AttachmentFile").val() != null && $("#Attachment_AttachmentFile").val() != "") {
            var filename = $("#Attachment_AttachmentFile").val().split('\\').pop().replace(" ", "");
            $("#Attachment_StorageName").val(filename);
            $("#filename").val(filename);
            $("#attachmentFileerror span").css("display", "none");
            var fileSize=0;
            var maxFileSize = 10240000 // 10MB -> 10000 * 1024
            fileSize = $("#" + "Attachment_AttachmentFile")[0].files[0].size //size in kb
            if(fileSize>maxFileSize){
                $("#Filesize").html("Please choose file less than 10MB");
                $("#Filesize").css("display", "block");
                $('#filename').val('');
            }
            else{
                $("#Filesize").css("display", "none");
            }
        }
        else
            $("#Attachment_StorageName").val("");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Rion for making the Edits.. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider explicitly clearing out the contents of your file `<input>` when the file that was added was too large. This should reset the `onchange()` event so that it will trigger again (as it will only be triggered if the actual file name is different) :

```
if(fileSize>maxFileSize){
       $("#Filesize").html("Please choose file less than 10MB");
       $("#Filesize").css("display", "block");
       $('#filename').val('');
       $("#Attachment_AttachmentFile").val('')'
}
```

Comment: You are right about that CodeCaster. I'll change it to better reflect that.

Comment: @RionWilliams i modified the function according to your suggestion. but that doesn't work.. I've modified  $("#Attachment_AttachmentFile").val(null);  and  $('#filename').val(null); Is their any other way.. Appreciate your help

Comment: Does this only occur if the file is too large? Or can you only seem to set the file a single time at all? I've updated my code as I don't think the `val()` call was the issue at all.